# Is it possible to connect to a microsoft database like sage from a Linux server?

Tags: linux, odbc, sage-line-50

The documentation of sage says this.
You have a Linux Server (Operating system:openSUSE 11.1 + Plesk 9.5) not a windows Server Thus the technical specifications for the Sage Line 50 are not met and cannot be installed on the Server you have.

Sage line 50 Technical specifications: (http://shop.sage.co.uk/accounts.aspx)
Compatible operating systems
Windows XP Service Pack 3
Windows Vista
Windows 7 
Windows Server 2008
Windows Server 2003

I know sage says this, but i also know you Linux boys are great. Is there any possibility of this happenening or must i get a windows based server

Any information would be great

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to hosting, not connecting.  You will need a Windows server.

Comment: for example. if i have a mysql database with invoices stored on my linux server. I need to transfer them to my computer straight into sage's database

Comment: Any statement that includes "import" and "sage" is enough to send me walking quickly in the other direction.   Sorry not more help.

Answer (score 0):

Sage is not a microsoft database its a third party app written by Sage. Sage uses a flat file system to store data so technically you could store the data on a linux server using samba and connect to the network path on your windows client to access the data. probably not supported but it would def work.